# Error with gradle in android

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I updated the last version of android studio(3.0.1)
and when`gradle`was built, an error occurred, the error is:
`Error:null value in entry: fakeOutputDirectory=null`.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the .gradle directory in the root project directory and rebuild project will fix the problem.